# Move a specific node

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I'm new to xslt, and I'm out of ideas now. Hopefully you peeps can help me back on track.

Given the following XML which is delivered to us from 3rd party:

```
<orderbatch>
<orders>
<order>
<id>1</id>
<customerid>2001</customerid>
<articleid>345</articleid>
</order>
</orders>
<customers>
<customer>
<id>2001</id>
<name>John Smith</name>
</customer>
</customers>
</orderbatch>
```

if I want to move the corresponding customer node under the order node via xslt, to get this output:

```
<orderbatch>
<orders>
<order>
<id>1</id>
<customerid>2001</customerid>
<articleid>345</articleid>
<customer>
<id>2001</id>
<name>John Smith</name>
</customer>
</order>
</orders>
<customers>
<customer>
<id>2001</id>
<name>John Smith</name>
</customer>
</customers>
</orderbatch>
```

I have a working xslt with a fixed value, but I'm a little at a loss how to parameterize it:

```
<xsl:output method="xml"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:key name="customerList" match="/orderbatch/customers/customer" use="id"/>

<xsl:template match="order">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select="id"/>
        <customer>
            <xsl:value-of select="key('customerList', '2001')"/>            
        </customer>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

For some reason, I cannot use xsl:variable, current()/customerid instead of the '2001', as those result in an empty  node at the order node (while the customer is present in the customerlist). So, the question is, how do I parameterize the '2001' in the select of the copy block? (or am I completely doing something wrong here?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For copying your customer, don't use value-of but copy-of.

```
<xsl:template match="order">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="customerid"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="key('customerList', customerid)" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

BTW, current() is not mandatory here, as order is the context node.